# Оптимизация функции в scipy

Tags: python, scipy

Пытаюсь максимизировать значение F1-метрики в задаче линейной регрессии. Необходимо найти оптимальное значение параметра К, при котором значение метрики будет максимальным. Функция get_f1(k, *args) получает на вход параметр К и 2 вектора - фактический и предсказанный.
Далее, создаются 3 пары фактических и предсказанных векторов, которые подаются на вход функции, а также вектор коэффициентов.

```
import scipy.optimize as sp
def get_f1(k, *args):
    T = 0.1*k
    predicted = []
    for actual, pred in zip(args):
        for pr in zip(pred>T):
            predicted.append(pr)

    return 1-f1_score(actual, predicted)

actual = [actual_1, actual_10, actual_11]
predicted = [predicted_1, predicted_10, predicted_11]
coeff = []
for args in zip(actual, predicted):
    coeff.append(sp.minimize(get_f1(*args), x0=0))
```

При последовательной передаче в функцию двух векторов все работает нормально.
Но при вызове функции как аргумента функционала оптимизации 
    sp.minimize(get_f1(*args), x0=0)
выдается ошибка:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-255eb7b545a6> in <module>()
 23     #f1 = get_f1(6, args)
 24     print args
---> 25     coeff.append(sp.minimize(get_f1(*args), x0=0))
 26 
 27 

<ipython-input-18-255eb7b545a6> in get_f1(k, *args)
 8     #pred_1 = args[1]
  9     #print actual, pred_1
---> 10     for actual, pred in zip(args):
 11         for pr in zip(pred>T):
 12             predicted.append(pr)

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

т.е. второй вектор не передается на вход функции.

Как корректно передать функцию с аргументами для оптимизации?

Comment: Может и не стоит удалять вопрос, если нашлось решение, лучше его опубликоваить...  Если  нет ответа, может кто-нибуть ответит... Двоих вопрос заинтересовал...